# Is every uncountable, homogeneous connected $T_2$-space isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

We say a space $(X,\tau)$ is *homogeneous* if for any $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $\varphi:X\to X$ such that $\varphi(x) = y$.

What is an example of a connected, homogeneous $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ with $|X| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ such that $(X,\tau)$ is not homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$?

Comment: How about the weak topology on a separable Banach space?  It's not metrizable nor even first countable, so can't be homeomorphic to any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this search](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7EFirst%20Countable%20%2B%20%24T_2%24%20%2B%20Connected%20%2B%20Homogeneous) in $\pi$-base, the *sigma product of incountably many copies of* $\mathbb{R}$ (no longer in pi-Base as of 2023 March) and the [*boolean product topology on* $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000107) are connected, $T_2$ and homogeneous.

However, they are *not* first countable, hence they cannot be homeomorphic to subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

Comment: Well, there is probably a mistake in $\pi$-base, since the second space I gave is the box topology in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, which is *not* connected (Steen-Seebach, Counterexamples in Topology, p. 128-129).

Comment: If you actually click on the "connected" listing for that space, it says "this is wrong, please delete me".  It seems that the Github code for $\pi$-base correctly says "false": https://github.com/pi-base/data/blob/master/spaces/S000107/properties/P000036.md.  I don't know why they are out of sync.  The "this is wrong" text doesn't even appear in the git history of that file.

Answer (score 4):

Or take the long line: $\omega_1\times[0,1)$ with the lexicographic order, minus the first point. Every bounded open interval is isomorphic to $(0,1)$, so it is homogeneous. It is first-countable but not second-countable, hence not embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Comment: This example is now in pi-base: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%20%2B%20%24T_2%24%20%2B%20Connected%20%2B%20Homogeneous%2B~Second%20Countable

Comment: @PatrickR That link does not show the space (yet)

Comment: Sorry, there needed to be a maintenance push internal to pi-base.  It should be there now.